# Equal importance of terms when using "in addition to" and "as well as"?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, synonyms

Please consider the sentence below:

> This section contains some numbers **as well as** a description.

In this case it feels like both terms (numbers and description) are of equal importance. The numbers arguably slightly more importance since they are mentioned first.

Now consider this:

> This section contains some numbers **in addition to** a description.

To me this implies that the numbers are now supplementing the description, making the description the most important term.

Since 'as well as' and 'in addition to' are often listed as synonyms, I would like to know if they both assume the terms are of equal importance, or if the latter indeed implies a more important part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a case where "as well as" and "in addition to" wouldn't be treated as synonyms.

Both conjunctions imply that the latter term was more expected or more important, and that the first term may have been less important in the situation described or unexpected to the reader. In your examples, the writer is calling attention to the fact that the section contains numbers, and not just a description as the reader might expect.

If both terms were equal, you should simply use "and" as the conjunction.

Answer (score -2):

> This section contains some numbers **as well as** a description.

This places no emphasis. You have numbers, and you also have a description.

> This section contains some numbers **in addition to** a description.

This places the emphasis on description. You have a description, and you add numbers.

Basically, use *as well as* when interchangeably with *and*, and use *in addition to* when the first term was added onto the second term.

> members of the board were paid a small allowance **in addition to** their normal salary

You normally get a salary - now you also get an allowance.

> a shop that sold books **as well as** newspapers

The shop sells books and newspapers.

Comment: Definitions found https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS726US726&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=in+addition+to and https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS726US726&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=as+well+as

Comment: Neither phrase in itself implies a chronological ordering. And you're wrong about "as well as." Here are some links that explain why: http://site.uit.no/english/grammar/aswellas/ http://www.dailywritingtips.com/as-well-as-does-not-mean-and/

Comment: @relaxing I stand corrected. However, in addition to is not perfectly synonymous with as well as, at least how I've seen it used.

Comment: @StephenS, I was under this exact same assumption, but apparently not.

Comment: @relaxing would you mind including those references in your own answer? I guess that would make clear where it is coming from.